# Listbox search and delete

Tags: excel, vba, search, listbox

My datasheet:
sheet ("Database") - A1 to L10000 (entries)
Headers of each Column in A1 to L1

I tried to search the sheet with a userform. I used a ComboBox because there are always the same Substances (25 different Substances).

For the output I used a Listbox.

I want to delete the selected output from the search function in my sheet ("database").

**For example**
Search after "substance 1" [ComboBox]

After the search:

*Listbox*
Columnhead is empty (How can I show the column head after the search?)
First row: substance 1
Second row : substance 1
...

I select the second row and press the Button "Delete".
Now it deletes a different entry not the one selected.

How do I delete the correct row with the selected information?

**VBA Excel Code:**

**Listbox - Entries of the database sheet**

```vb
Private Sub Refresh_data()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")

Dim lr As Long
lr = Sheets("Database").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If lr = 1 Then lr = 2 
    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 13
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .RowSource = "Database!A2:L" & lr
    End With
End Sub
```

**Search in the sheet "database"**

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()  'Search Button

Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim row As Long

Worksheets("Database").Activate

UserForm2.ListBox1.RowSource = "" 

Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")

For row = 2 To sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    If InStr(1, sh1.Cells(row, 2).Value, Me.ComboBox.Value) <> 0 Then

        Me.ListBox1.AddItem sh1.Cells(row, 1).Value                               
        Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = sh1.Cells(row, 2).Value  
        Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = sh1.Cells(row, 3).Value  
        Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = sh1.Cells(row, 4).Value  
        Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 4) = sh1.Cells(row, 5).Value  
        Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 5) = sh1.Cells(row, 6).Value 
        Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 6) = sh1.Cells(row, 7).Value  
        Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 7) = sh1.Cells(row, 8).Value 
        Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 8) = sh1.Cells(row, 9).Value  
        Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 9) = sh1.Cells(row, 10).Value 

    End If

Next Zeile

End Sub
```

**Delete the entry**

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click() 'Delete Button

Worksheets("Database").Activate

Dim a As String
Dim i As Long

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1             
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then         
    Rows(i + 2).EntireRow.Delete            
    End If
Next

Call Refresh_data 

End Sub
```

Comment: Since you selectively loaded the list box, its index does not correspond to the sheet row, anymore. Your code should also place in the list the row number and use it when try deletion. Your code loads only the row where in column B:B the code founds the Combo value. Isn't it what you want/need when loading the combo?

Comment: Thanks FaneDure for the fast answer, but how could I do this?

Comment: I compare the ComboBox(CB) with the column B,because in Column B are all the substances listed. After the search I found the substances which I selected with the CB. For example "combobox=sub1" and I found all sub1 substances. But I can't delete the right row where the information is stored in. I used a CB because it is always the same 25 substances and it much easier to search, because you just need to seleced the substance without tipping. The other columns cotain informations about the substance, like measuring date and so on. So I want to delete the whole row with all the information.

Comment: **Are there more occurrences** of "sub1" in B:B column? Do you want deleting the row on the sheet, or removing the selected line from the list box? If more occurrences and want deleting the sheet row, would you decide which row to be deleted, looking to the other parameters on the selected row?

Comment: Yes, there are more sub1 in B:B. It is a database for the lab. I want to remove the row on the sheet and also from the list box. The other parameters are Informations about Lot, measuring date, slope from the calibration. I have more sub 1 because I have to calibrate the sub1 after I change something on the measuring maschine(LC/MS). The other parameters are also showing up in the listbox and help me to decide if I want to delete the data from the sheet. For example I have a wrong information for the substance on the measuring date 22.01.22, so I could deleted it from the database.

Comment: The maximum allowed number of columns in a list box is 10. Do you need all columns which your code inputs in the list box? Otherwise, it is possible to load more, but placing an array in the `List` property, which is more complicated for your case.

Comment: No I don't need all the columns from the database in my listbox.

Comment: When you load the list box, should the code clear the list box content and add only the items which match the combo value? Or should add the new items, **even if they already exists** in the list box?

Comment: It should clear the list box content and add only the items which match the combo value

Comment: Does the listbox allow more than one row to be selected ?

Comment: I am afraid that your whole code should be redesigned in a different way. You cannot use `.RowSource = "Database!A2:L" & lr` and then add extra items using `AddItem`. I mean, you can, but you loose the reference to the sheet row.

Comment: No, you can only select one row in the listbox.

Comment: You do not need anything if you keep only `.RowSource` loading way and refresh it when add and delete items. But if you want selectively loading it it is more complicated, even if not impossible.

Comment: Yes I know that I have to redesigne it but I have no idea how. I already used the addItem instead of the .RowSource, but in that way I couldn't see the columnheads, thats why I changed back to the .RowSoure. Sorry but I just started to learn vba and I have no idea anymore how I could see the columnheads and fill the listbox and search in the listbox and delete the selected output from the search.

Answer (score 0):

Add the row number to the search results. You can only delete from search results not if list box is showing the full data.  I coloured the results in yellow to show difference.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Refresh_data()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
    
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = Sheets("Database").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    
     If lr = 1 Then lr = 2
     With Me.ListBox1
        .BackColor = vbWhite
        .ColumnWidths = ""
        .ColumnCount = 12
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .RowSource = "Database!A2:L" & lr
     End With
 End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()  'Search Button

    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, c As Long, data, s As String
    Dim LastRow As Long, row As Long, i As Long
    
    Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
    LastRow = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row
    data = sh1.Range("A1:L" & LastRow).Value
    s = Me.ComboBox.Value
    
    With Me.ListBox1
        .RowSource = ""
        .ColumnCount = 10
        .ColumnWidths = "0" ' hide row numbers
        .BackColor = RGB(240, 240, 200)
        
        For row = 2 To LastRow
            If InStr(1, data(row, 2), s) <> 0 Then
                .AddItem row
                i = .ListCount - 1
                For c = 1 To 9
                   .List(i, c) = data(row, c)
                Next
            End If
        Next
        
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton6_Click() 'Delete Button
       
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, i As Long, r As Long
    Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
    
    With ListBox1
        ' only delete from filtered list
        If .ColumnCount > 10 Then Exit Sub
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) = True Then
                r = .List(i, 0) ' row in col 0
                sh1.Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Call CommandButton7_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Wuhu, perfect. Thanks you so much!!!!!